# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'control')

Tags: swiper.js

I'm using the swiper js library in my project. Where I want to show the product thumbnail gallery on page load and the same gallery thumbnail in modal but it's not working properly. I'm getting an error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'control')
How can I fix it?

I've changed my code by following some suggestions on git but still, it's the same.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV8aq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and I forgot to add 'Controller' it to my JS import.

So I added it like this:

```
import Swiper, { Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination, Controller, EffectFade, } from 'swiper'; 

Swiper.use([Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination, Controller, EffectFade]);
```

But not sure if this is your problem without seeing some code.